# Django : m2m relationship create two line instead of one

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have extended the UserModel this way :

```
# users/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # add additional fields in here
    credit = models.IntegerField(default=200)
    follow = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='follow')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

But I am stuck as to how I should add/remove a follower. I have created a view with :

```
@login_required
def follow(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=user_id)
    if CustomUser.objects.filter(follow=user.pk).exists():
        request.user.follow.remove(user)
    else:
        request.user.follow.add(user)
    return redirect('profil', user_id)
```

---

### Issue :

Let's say `request.user.pk` is 1 and `user_id` is 2.

For the `add` part (in the `else`), I would expect a new line in database with `from_customuser_id=1` and `to_customuser_id=2` however, it creates two lines:

- one with `from_customuser_id=1` and `from_customuser_id=2` as expected
- one with `from_customuser_id=2` and `from_customuser_id=1` which I don't need.

And for the `remove` part (in the `if`), I would expect it to only remove the line

- `from_customuser_id=1` and `from_customuser_id=2`

But it removes the two lines.

I read the [doc about django models relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/) but didn't found how to solve this issue.

### Question :

How should I update my code in order to have the `add` method to only insert one line with `from_customuser_id=1`, `from_customuser_id=2` and the `remove` method to only delete this line (assuming the current user have the id 1).

---

Not sure if it is relevant but for sake of completeness this is the related part of my urls.py :

```
path('follow/<int:user_id>', views.follow, name='follow'),
path('unfollow/<int:user_id>', views.follow, name='unfollow'),
```

And this is how I call them in templates :

```
{% if follow %}
    <a href="{% url 'follow' user_profil.id %}">
        Unfollow {{ user_profil.username }}
    </a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'unfollow' user_profil.id %}">
        Follow {{ user_profil.username }}
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a ManyToManyField it essentially creates a relationship between both the objects. This also allows you to do reverse lookups.

For example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=100)

class Pet(models.Model):
    owners = models.ManyToMany(Person, related_name="pets")
    name = model.CharField(max_length=100)

bob = Person.objects.create(name="Bob")
john = Person.objects.create(name="John")
kitty_kat = Pet.objects.create(name="Kitty Kat")
kitty_kat.owners.set([bob, john])
```

According to these models one pet can be owned by multiple people, and one person can have multiple pets. So if I do

```
bob.pets.all()          # I get kitty kat
kitty_kay.owners.all()  # I get bob & john
```

When this relationship is supposed to be on the same model, you end up creating two relationships. One as the normal one & one for the reverse.

For example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=100)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='follow') 

bob = Person.objects.create(name="Bob")
john = Person.objects.create(name="John")
john.followers.add(bob)

bob.follow.all()       # I get john... notice I use follow and not followers
john.followers.all()   # I get bob
```

In order to avoid this you can pass `symmetrical=False` to the field and one one row will be created

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='+', symmetrical=False)
```

Setting the `related_name` to anything starting with `+` will also prevent reverse lookups (which you don't need in this case)